# WhatsApp calls with background data disabled

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data, whatsapp.app

With Mobile Data and background app refresh turned off, can WhatsApp receive a call while the Wi-Fi is enabled, and the iPhone is connected to a Wi-Fi access point with active Internet connection?

If the iPhone is resting on a table, will I receive a normal WhatsApp call or not? Or will it remain closed, unless I pick the mobile in hand and turn-on the screen.

I will be using my iPhone in another country with international roaming active.

Comment: yes you will .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will receive the calls on WhatsApp normally, even with the background data turned off as long as you are connected to the Internet (via Wi-Fi in your case).

WhatsApp makes use of a framework called VoIPKit available in iPhone software development kit, which enables it to receive audio/video calls even when in background/not running status or with the device in sleep mode/locked state/screen turned off.

Comment: Is this valid for Android Phones as well? Does call come in on Android phones when background data is off for both mobile data and WiFi?

Comment: @ranka47 I don't know this for a fact, but I would guess with a high degree of certainly that it would work.